# How to add a whitespace before "((VERB)" only if it is not preceded by a space or the beginning of the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

```
import re

#input string example:
input_text = "((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) ár((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) Los computadores pueden ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros)"


#this give me a raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern") re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
#input_text = re.sub(r"(?<!^|\s)\(\(VERB\)", " ((VERB)", input_text)

#and this other option simply places a space in front of all ((VERB) ) 
# without caring if there is a space or the beginning of the string in front 
input_text = re.sub(r"(^|\s)\(\(VERB\)", lambda match: match.group(1) + "((VERB)", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

I have tried using `(^|\s)` as it is a capturing group that looks for the start of the string `^` or a whitespace just before the pattern `"((VERB)"`. Another pattern option could be with a non-capturing group `(?:|)` or better still using a context limiter like look-behind `(?<!^|\s)`

This is the output you should be getting when running this script:

```
"((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) ár ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) Los computadores pueden ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert a non whitespace char to the left:

```
(?<=\S)\(\(VERB\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cGAAX0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jze8TJ)

In the replacement use a space followed by the full match `r" \g<0>"`

```
import re

input_text = "((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) ár((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) Los computadores pueden ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros)"
input_text = re.sub(r"(?<=\S)\(\(VERB\)", r" \g<0>", input_text)
print(input_text)
```

Output

```
((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) ár ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros) Los computadores pueden ((VERB)ayudar a nosotros)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using a lookbehind could be to match on any character except whitespaces before `((VERB)`:

```
([^\s])(\(\(VERB\))
```

substitute with

```
\1 \2
```

- `(` - start of capture group 1

  - `[^\s]` - match on a single character that is not a whitespace
- `)` - end of capture group 1
- `(` - start of capture group 2

  - `\(\(VERB\)` - literal match on `((VERB)`
- `)` - end of capture group 2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6iy2tk/1)